# CSS using firebug with tab computed style question

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the firebug for looking at a layout in a select box. On the right column of the firebug if I select option 1 from the select table, I can see in the computed column,

font-family **verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif**
font-size   **13px**
font-weight **400**

However, when I change the selection to the 2nd or 3rd selection, suddenly the whole page looses its layout, and in the computed column of firebug, there are some changes with these formats :

font-family **serif**
font-size   **16px**
font-weight **400**

The strange thing is that I already delete all the css file related to this layout, but I can not udnerstand where it gets these different font everytime I change the selection of the select table. Any suggestion?

Thank you for any kindness response

Comment: any chance for a live example (or link to site) ?

Comment: i'm terribly sorry, but it is not possible to upload this web (yet).. If it's possible, maybe you can suggest some rough ideas instead?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you use CSS reset? Could it be that you're running into browser defaults?

Comment: yes, I am also thinking that the serif 16 px 400 is default layout of firefox, but I do not know how to solve this. the problem occurs only in firefox, and not in IE nor Chrome. I did not use CSS reset, I just deleted all .css files I have.

Comment: In that case I strongly recommend checking this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet

Comment: Thanks, but I tried different reset css and I still find out that the problem is that firefox always 'overwrite' my default layout (with serif 16 px) everytime I change my selection in select table. How can I avoid the firefox default layout to load?

Comment: @heike: from my own experience, that's either a typo in your class name or a missing comma in the CSS rule which causes it to be skipped. Do your intended rules show up at all in the "Style" tab?